# Card Deck shuffle and display applet

Tags: java, random, applet, shuffle

I've written some code to create an ArrayList of cards I downloaded, and now am trying to shuffle them and then display them by using the paint method.  How would I display ten cards using the g.drawImage?

```
    import java.awt.Image;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.util.*;

public class DeckofCards1 extends Applet {

public void init ( ) {
    String[] suits = {"c", "s", "h", "d"};
    String[] values = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "j", "q", "k"};

    ArrayList<Image> images = new ArrayList<Image>( );
    for(String suit : suits){
            for(String value : values){
                 Image img = getImage ( getDocumentBase ( ), "images/" + suit +              value + ".gif" );
      images.add(img);
                     }
    }
    Collections.shuffle ( images ); //get ten cards randomly?
    }

    public void paint ( Graphics g ) { //display ten cards here?

        g.drawImage ( img, 10, 10, this );
        g.drawImage ( img, 10, 10, this );
        g.drawImage ( img, 10, 10, this );      
        g.drawImage ( img, 10, 10, this );
        g.drawImage ( img, 10, 10, this );
        g.drawImage ( img, 10, 30, this ); //what goes in place of img (which I know isn't right, simply a placeholder for now
        g.drawImage ( img, 10, 30, this );
        g.drawImage ( img, 10, 30, this );
        g.drawImage ( img, 10, 30, this );
        g.drawImage ( img, 10, 30, this );

    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at my answer. It should be able to guide you to your solution... Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I had a quick look and it seems like you can use this piece of code to get img:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(imageSrc);
```

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html

Also, depending on where you want to draw those images, you can probably put it into a loop and control the coordinates using the loop variables.

Make images a variable within your class (so you can use it in the paint function).

```
public class DeckofCards1 extends Applet {

    private ArrayList<Image> images;
    ....
```

In your init function, change the Image creation line from

```
Image img = getImage ( getDocumentBase ( ), "images/" + suit + value + ".gif");
```

to

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("images/" + suit + value + ".gif"));
```

In your paint function, change it so that it loops through the images array and for each, draws it using this

```
for(int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {

    g.drawImage(images.get(i), i*10, i*10, null);
}
```

Check out this pastebin for an updated version of your code that should compile if you have the images: http://pastebin.com/43t7zhYL

Updated pastebin using a different image read method: http://pastebin.com/15tigYFd

Comment: Thanks so much for the help.  When I compile the code it says the BufferedImage img = ... and in the for loop the g.drawImage, both those symbols cannot be found.

Comment: I am not extremely familiar with BufferedImages but after looking through the documentation, I don't need to import anything do I?

Comment: Hi - sorry, I only just got home. The read() function in ImageIO actually requires you to give it a File object. BufferedImage also needs to be imported (you can let eclipse fix this for you, it's from java.awt.image.BufferedImage). The read line will also need to be surrounded by a try and catch (once again you can use eclipse to fix this for you automatically). I have updated my answer to reflect some of this. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I've added a link to a pastebin at the end of the answer. It contains an updated version of your class which should hopefully compile with the images in the right folder :) If it works, feel free to mark this answer as correct. Let me know!

Comment: Hey Mick,  Thanks for the code, it compiles but when it runs my Command Prompt freaks out saying it can't read the input files? Thanks for the attempt however.

Comment: Hey Brad, make sure the files are in the right location. If they are, I suspect the read method I'm using doesn't support gif. Try replacing the image reading line with this: Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("images/" + suit + value + ".gif"); I have added a new pastebin that uses this method instead.

Comment: Thanks! There needs to be more people like you in these forums!

Comment: No worries :) If it's working now, feel free to accept this as the answer to your question. Accepting answers also helps keep stackoverflow more organised.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning shuffling, `Collections.shuffle ( images );` will permute the elements of `images` randomly. But I recommand adding this line :

```
private final Random random = new Random(4454776669L);
```

and using `Collections.shuffle ( images, random);` instead. Here the number 4454776669L is a seed for the pseudorandom number generator, and when you use the same seed you reproduce the same sequence of random numbers, which can be useful if you want to reproduce the same game or just for debugging purposes.

Comment: Once I shuffle the cards...how can I display the first ten?